# Refresh two Kendo grids

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have two Kendo grids on the same page, the upper grid contains 'parent' records, the lower grid displays the 'children' of a parent when the parent is clicked.

When I perform an action on a parent, I want to a) update the database (both parent and child records are affected), b) reload the data in the parent grid and then c) reload the data in the child grid.

I can do a) and b), but c) doesn't work.

Here's my function:

```
// Restore a Soft-Deleted person
var processRestoreURL = crudServiceBaseUrl + '?method=restorePerson';
function restorePerson(id, row){
    if (confirm('#getResource("person.detail.confirmrestore")#')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: processRestoreURL,
            data: {
                PERS_KY: id
            },
            success: function (data){
                // Refresh the datasource so the row updates itself
                $("#list").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

                // TO DO: Make the Organisation tab reload with the restored data
                $("#organisationGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
                    // doesn't work :-(
                    // Seems to execute BEFORE the datasource refresh
                    // Maybe I just need to reload the tab here, no need to reread the datasource?


            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("Error while restoring person"+ "\n"+ xhr + "\n"+ textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How do I get #organisationGrid to refresh?

---

### EDIT

```
//on dataBound event
// 1: Change search operator to contain for every 'string' type
// 2: restore previous selected rows
// 3: Save person filter information in cookie
function dataBoundFunction(){
    //Search change
    setTimeout(function(){
        var header;
        $('.k-header').each(function(i){
            if ($(this).data('kendoColumnMenu')) {
                header = $(this).data('kendoColumnMenu');
                if (header.filterMenu) {
                    header.menu.bind('open', function(e){
                        if ($(e.item).is('.k-filter-item')) {
                            header = $('.k-header:eq(' + i + ')').data('kendoColumnMenu');
                            var popup = header.filterMenu.popup;
                            if (!$(popup.element).data('alreadyOpened')) {
                                var select = this.element.find('select:first');
                                var option = select.children('option:contains("Contains")');
                                if (option.length > 0) {
                                    select.data('kendoDropDownList').select(option.index());
                                    header.filterMenu.filterModel.set("filters[0].operator", "contains");
                                }
                                $(popup.element).data('alreadyOpened', true);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    header.filterMenu.form.bind('reset', function(){
                        $(this).parent().data('kendoFilterMenu').popup.element.data('alreadyOpened', false);
                    });
                }
            }
            else
                if ($(this).data('kendoFilterMenu')) {
                    header = $(this).data('kendoFilterMenu');
                    header.popup.bind('open', function(){
                        if (!$(this.element).data('alreadyOpened')) {
                            header = $('.k-header:eq(' + i + ')').data('kendoFilterMenu');
                            var select = this.element.find('select:first');
                            var option = select.children('option:contains("Contains")');
                            if (option.length > 0) {
                                select.data('kendoDropDownList').select(option.index());
                                header.filterModel.set("filters[0].operator", "contains");
                            }
                            $(this.element).data('alreadyOpened', true);
                        }
                    });
                    header.form.bind('reset', function(){
                        $(this).parent().data('kendoFilterMenu').popup.element.data('alreadyOpened', false);
                    });
                }
        });
    }, 1);
    //selected row
    var view = gridList.dataSource.view();
    var currentSelection = gridList.wrapper.data('currentSelection');
    for(var i = 0; i < view.length;i++){
        if(checkedIds[view[i].id]){
            gridList.table.find("tr[data-uid='" + view[i].uid + "']")
                .find("input[type=checkbox]")
                .attr("checked","checked");
        }
    }
    if(currentSelection) {
        gridList.select('[data-uid=' + gridList.dataSource.get(currentSelection).uid + ']');
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the databound event on the parent grid to refresh the child grid? If not that is probably the way to go then any changes that occur in the parent grid's datasource should then fire off a request to rebind the child grid for you. If you need an example I am happy to provide one.

Comment: Err... yes please! That would be excellent!

Comment: Actually, regarding the dataBound thing, the parent grid already has a dataBound attribute that calls a separate function dataBoundFunction(), which does a whole bunch of other stuff. (You'll guess by now I'm working on legacy code).

The function is in the edit of my original post. Perhaps you can suggest a change to it that will refresh my #organisationGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple demo hopefully showing you how to do this:

http://dojo.telerik.com/UfeDO

the important bit is this bit in the first grid:

```
  dataBound: function (e) {
      console.log(e);

      reboundTimes = reboundTimes + 1;

      $('#newConsole').html('<strong>rebinding child grid now: have done this: ' + reboundTimes + ' time(s)</strong>');
      $('#grid2').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
  },
```

All this is doing is once the DataBound event is fired it is logging to console (just to show you what the event has done) as well as incrementing a counter to show you that this is firing the event off.

Once this has then fired off it then calls the second grid and then fires off the read event on the dataSource.

Any issues let me know.